# Handling WPF Canvas Resize Correctly/Efficiently

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am attaching working code. My Question: am I handling resize correctly/efficiently? I Draw a scene on my WPF Canvas Circle at Center of Canvas and a Vertical and Horizontal line in the center of the Canvas. When I resize the canvas I Clear all the Children and Redraw the entire scene based on the new Canvas Size. Is there a better way of doing this with say RenderTransform etc? FYI My real App is much more complex than this simple example I just wanted to post this code because it demonstrates the shortest code to demonstrate the real optimization I am attempting.

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="Sample2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400"  SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas">

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Sample2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void DrawScene()
        {
             MainCanvas.Children.Clear();

            double ctrX = MainCanvas.ActualWidth    / 2;
            double ctrY = MainCanvas.ActualHeight   / 2;

            Ellipse elps = new Ellipse();
            elps.Width = elps.Height = 100;
            elps.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(elps);
            Canvas.SetLeft(elps, ctrX-elps.Width/2);
            Canvas.SetTop(elps,  ctrY-elps.Height/2);

            Line lnVertical   = new Line();
            lnVertical.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
            lnVertical.X1 = lnVertical.X2 = ctrX;
            lnVertical.Y1 = 0;
            lnVertical.Y2 = MainCanvas.ActualHeight;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(lnVertical);

            Line lnHorizontal   = new Line();
            lnHorizontal.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            lnHorizontal.X1 = 0;
            lnHorizontal.X2 = MainCanvas.ActualWidth;
            lnHorizontal.Y1 = lnHorizontal.Y2 = ctrY;
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(lnHorizontal);
        }
        //private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{

        //}

        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawScene();
        }
    }
}
```

My Actual App is data Driven and looks like this. The only real Data Driven Elements are (Color/Type) and Depth in the Well Pipe: The Circle positions are calcd in VM for position so as to avoid overlap
[image]

Comment: Instead of Ellipse, Line etc. controls you may use Path controls with appropriate EllipseGeometry, LineGeometry etc. geometries assigned to their Data property. Then you may assign a common Transform to all geometries and would *never* need to redraw anything, but just update the single Transform object.

Comment: Now I must say that there are hundreds of Data Driven FrameworkElements location and size line/circle elements in my actual App.that are placed. Indeed a single element needs to independently reflect its underlying changes without affecting the rest of the scene.

Comment: You are just redrawing to keep everything centered?

Comment: In the example yes. In my actual app no.. With one Qualification. All elements have a known 'offset' from center.

Comment: Okay Clemmens:I think I am beginning to see it your way. Is there a way I can post a pic of my actual app here so you can see what I am taling about?

Comment: Can't you just upload an image?

Comment: I added a pic and brief explanation. I am beginning to think about a sc enario where I have an ItemTemplate Whose ItemSource is the collectgion of WellTargetDepths and the ItemsPanelTemplate is a Geometry. Hmmm let me see if a Geometry is an acceptable ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: Okay I looked at Path Statements. It seems that a Path has only one Stroke Color thickness. Is that correct idea? If I go about creating a Path Statement I would  need a Path Container for each Stroke Color and Thickness. Is that Correct?

Comment: Right, Path (as all other Shape-derived elements) has a single stroke color (actually a Brush) and thickness.

Answer (score 0):

I found the ultimate answer to this question through talking to a friend. clemens was nearby and probably created a very efficient answer to the question if I were able to use a single stroke color. The resize event is handled in my application no with a simple Invalidate for each child framework elelent.

```
  SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {

            WellCanvas.SetCoordinateSystem(wm.OverallStartDepth,
                                            wm.OverallEndDepth,

                                            wm.OverallEndDepth,
                                            wm.OverallStartDepth);
            **// This seemed to solve the problem**
            foreach (FrameworkElement elem in WellCanvas.Children)
                elem.InvalidateVisual();

        };
```